# Parse.com notification panel returning error 500

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, http-status-code-500

I was doing some changes and tests in my app using Parse.com push framework, and I was sending some push tests and suddenly, when I came back to the push notifications panel in my dashboard, it returned error 500 and I really don't know whats happening.

The only irregular thing I was doing was sending large queries that returned error that the max buffer was 64K for where and data clause.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems to be a parse.com error. They are already working on it.

If I have some news I will post it.